# Can't copy the file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing small script that copy files to special folder. The problem is in Copy command. It's claim me that I use wrong syntaxis to copy

```
$files = dir -r -path "Z:\graphics\" -i *.*

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    copy -path $file Z:\SatData\graphics\LastDays\
}
```

Also I want to create script that calculate size of files created 1day ago. I try to do next:

```
$today = Get-Date
$now = $today.Day
$now

$lastdays = $today.AddDays(-1)
$lastdays

$files = dir -r -path "Z:\graphics\" -i *.*

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
if ($file.CreationTime -eq $lastdays) # if file was create yesterday calculate it
    {
    $sum
    $sum = $sum + $file.length
    $sum/1MB

    $file.CreationTime

    }
else {}
}
```

The script simply do not find any files created yesterday, and I do now see any output. It's work only if set not -eq, but -lt
 but yesterday created files are present in folder

Comment: The first one works for me, can you please post the **exact** error message?

Comment: For me do not work :(
http://xmages.net/i/3098832
the text mean that there syntaxis error in file or in it's name

Comment: What happens when you add the `-whatif` parameter to your copy command?

Answer (score 2):

Use the pipeline:

```
dir -r -path Z:\graphics | copy-item -dest Z:\SatData\graphics\LastDays
```

To calculate files sizes (in MB):

```
$files = dir -r -path Z:\graphics | 
         where {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date} |
         measure -sum

$files.sum/1mb
```

Comment: Shay Levy, your second example do now work it's blaim that it's can evaluate -eq

Comment: looks like I was missing an opening parenthesis, updating it now.

Answer (score 1):

In your copy statement you need to reference the actual path because `dir` is returning a fileinfo object. For example: `copy -path $file.FullName Z:\SatData\graphics\LastDays\`

The second part of your question `$now` is a day number not a date. Try something like `$yesterday = (get-date).adddays(-1).date` and change your comparison to `if ($file.CreationTime.date -eq $yesterday)`

You need to use the date property because it sets the time to 00:00:00 for the comparison. If you don't you'll never match.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, use $file.FullName instead of just $file.

Comment: I tried to do it's with $fle.FullName but it's do now work. The screenshot are above